# ASUS RT-ACRH13 Router WLAN Speed issue

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Recently i upgraded from a very old 150 Mbps basic router to this ASUS router as i wanted good LAN speeds for streaming HD movies and games within my home. I thought this router would be an awesome upgrade compared to my basic router, but to my horror its a very very slight improvement, i am so pissed off , i think i may be doing something wrong so i need help.

Issue 1
WLAN speeds are pathetic, i get like 8 Mbps to 11 Mbps speeds?.. what nonsense is this, i am not talking about the internet speeds , my internet speed is just 10 Mbps so no issues there, but i expected my LAN speeds to be waaaaay better than this garbage speed. below is what was advertised , at least i thought i would get around 400 mbps lan speeds in my 5ghz band for streaming my PC games or movies

Dual-band 802.11ac Wi-Fi with concurrent speeds up to 867Mbps (5GHz) and 400Mbps (2.4GHz)

So now i thought i may be doing something wrong and here is my setup for streaming movies,

My PC has windows 10 and Killer Wireless-N 1202 Network Adapter card. it is connected with the 5ghz wifi and all my other devices are also using 5ghz

1. Connected my USB 3.0 HDD and moved some 1080p movies there, i get stream speeds of around 11 Mbps max
2. Installed Plex and streamed from my android device(note 4) again max around 11 Mbps
3. Used moonlight for streaming PC games, cant really find out the band width but games aren't playable
4. Copy pasted few movies between my PC and surface pro 3, i get only 5 mbps max

Note that i find out the stream speeds using my android device (bandiwdth meter in status bar and NetSpeedMonitor in PC)

Is my setup wrong, how in the world can i get good speeds and what is a more accurate way to measure the WLAN speeds , even my earlier router was giving almost similar speeds, i feel like i wasted so much money on this useless router

Issue 2
Network coverage, it was advertised as if this router covers a entire house both the ground floor and the first floor, my house just has one floor and this thing cant even cover the entire house .. huff (i am so angry at it , i want to just throw it in the garbage bin)

Please help me out guys , how can i get good WLAN speeds and good coverage ???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your PC adapter (Bigfoot Networks KillerN-1202 Notebook Wireless Card) has a max theoretical speed of 300Mbps (~150Mbps TCP Throughput) - So, you WILL NOT get "400Mbps (theoretical max, 200Mbps TCP throughput) lan speeds" with this PC wireless adapter.  No need to get upset here.

Second, based on the chart below:

1. 1 Mb/s for viewing on a laptop computer.
2. 2 Mb/s for viewing standard definition video (480p) on a TV
3. 4 Mb/s for viewing high-def video (720p, 1080p)
4. 5 Mb/s or more for the best audio and video experience
5. 15 Mb/s for 4K streaming

As you can see, movies are usually compressed and don't require 400Mbps to stream.  No need to get upset here.

On your bullet item 4 "Copy pasted few movies between my PC and surface pro 3, i get only 5 mbps max" - Microsoft reports as MB/s (Mega **Bytes** / Second), so 5MB/s = 40Mbps (Mega **Bits** / Second).  40Mbps is not ideal, but is pretty good.  To get >100Mbps, you'll need to be close to the access point with no obstructions between your PC and the WiFi access point.

**iPerf_Server_PC ((( wifi ))) Access Point -----LAN-----iPerf_Client_PC**

Iperf client pushes traffic to the server.  To measure downstream traffic, you have the server run on associated wifi station.

**On wifi associated station:**

iperf -s -w 256k (server side, typically on the wifi associated station)

**On LAN Station:**

iperf -c (ip address of server) -w 256k -i 2 -t 60 -l 100K -M 1400 -P 2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, as you said yes for streaming i dont need that bandwidth , but my point is why i dont get good throughput for copy pasting between two LAN systems, i tried this by sitting just next to the router .. i am  feeling some setting or something is preventing the speeds

Comment: Do you know how to use iperf? it's a free performance tool - Made updates on how to use the tool in my original comments (up above).